# How to extract file size of the files within .tar.gz using linux command?

Tags: linux, tar

I have one file with name config.tar.gz. Inside this tar file I have couple of files. Out of which I need to get size of one file.
I am trying following

```
tar -vtf config.tar.gz | grep sgr.txt
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r-- root/DIAGUSER 109568 2019-11-26 10:16:21 sgr.txt
```

From this I need to extract only size in human readable format. Something similar to "ls -sh sgr.txt"

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
tar -ztvf file.tar.gz 'specific_file' | awk '{print $3}'
```